# LDAP and Subversion: Who can access my repository

Tags: svn, ldap, httpd.conf

I use our Active Directory groups to verify access to our Subversion repository. We have the following setup in our `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Location /repo>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /mnt/svn/repositories/repo
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "Corporate Repostitory"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://ldap2.vegicorp.net:389 ldap3.vegicorp.net:389/OU=Users,DC=vegicorp,DC=NET?sAMAccountName" NONE
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=CM,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,DC=Vegicorp,DC=NET"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword swordfish
        Require ldap-group CN=Development,OU=Security Groups,DC=Vegicorp,DC=NET
        Require ldap-dn "CN=Release Management,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users, dc=Vegicorp,dc=net"
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /mnt/svn/repo
</Location>
```

Access to our repository is only suppose to be for the Release Management user (the one who uses Subversion for builds) and people in the group *Development*. However, I've recently found that a user who are not in the *Development* group does have access to our repository.

Is there an error somewhere in our configuration? Or, could there be another reason why this user has access to our repository?

Comment: Honestly, I think that because you have a double comma right after "OU=Security Groups,," it is causing an error, and possibly hang time. It's probably omitting that line entirely and not specifying any group to be required. Also, it's not in quotes (though I'm not sure if it needs to be?)

Comment: That double comma could be due to my editing of the actual file to remove corporate identifying information, and to simplify the levels to make them easier to see. However, thanks for that catch. I'll verify if that's the case in the actual file. If not, I'll remove that double column from my question.

Comment: It doesn't look like you were trying to omit any information. Unless you have a nested OU, then it is indeed an unintended double comma. Please also see my answer below, because the ldap-dn when specifying a user should not be in quotes.

Comment: JFYI - with Require ldap-group you will expect surprises, AFAICR

Comment: Sorry, the double comma was the result of a bad edit. I'll try removing the quotes around ldap-dn and see whether that helps. I know I need them with the `AuthLDAPUrl` clause. I thought the problem might be due to `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative` or that I needed a `Satisfy` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Location /repo>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /mnt/svn/repositories/repo
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Corporate Repostitory"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://ldap2.vegicorp.net:389 ldap3.vegicorp.net:389/OU=Users,DC=vegicorp,DC=NET?sAMAccountName" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=CM,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,DC=Vegicorp,DC=NET"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword swordfish
    Require ldap-group CN=Development,OU=Security Groups,DC=Vegicorp,DC=NET
    Require ldap-dn CN=Release Management,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users, dc=Vegicorp,dc=net
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /mnt/svn/repo
</Location>
```

You do not need quotes on the ldap-dn. Also, you need to remove the double comma in ldap-group "OU=Security Groups,,"

Please refer to http://www.held-im-ruhestand.de/software/apache-ldap-active-directory-authentication